# How to open a primefaces dialog via javascript if a tree node is clicked?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, tree, dialog

I have a tree in primefaces. The leaves of the tree contain data that I need to display/be able to change in a dialog that pops up when the node gets clicked. I identified how to call javascript when a node gets clicked (see the tree below). What I am looking for are answers to the following questions:

- How can I open up a primefaces dialog to display/edit the node in the onNodeClick function when the node is clicked?
- Is it possible to evaluate the node info in javascript to check if a node is a leave by checking .isLeave or the node type? The dialog only makes sense for leaves.
- How can I provide the node info to the dialog? The basic idea is to save the selected node in the backing bean an provide it to the dialog frome there (setSelectedNode / getSelectedNode). Is there another possibility?

Here is what my tree looks like:

```
<h:head>  
    <title>Tree</title>
    <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
    <script>
        function onNodeClick(node,event){
          do something...
        }
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:tree value="#{treeManager.rootNode}" var="node" dynamic="true" onNodeClick="onNodeClick(node,event)"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeManager.singleSelectedTreeNode}">
            <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
            </p:treeNode>
            <p:treeNode type="document" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-document">
                <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>            
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```